# Two Windows Boot Managers?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I was installing ubuntu alongside Windows and when I ran

```
$ efibootmgr
```

I was greeted with

```
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0005, 0004, 0003, 0000, 0006, 0002, 0001
Boot0000* HDD/SSD
Boot0001* LAN2
Boot0002* LAN1
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0005* ubuntu
Boot0006* USB Memory
```

Why are there two Windows Boot Managers on Boot0003* and Boot0004*?
Is it necessary to keep both or delete one?

Thank you